# Function to get all properties of an object

Tags: javascript

I'm fairly new at JavaScript, and I'm finding that JS is a language with what seems like an unusually high number of gotchas for the inexperienced, so some criticisms of this code would be particularly appreciated.

The function `getProperties` below is a relatively simple function that returns an array of the *names* (not the values) of all the properties that an object has (either "owned" or "inherited").  Here's the code, followed by some description of what it does:

```
function getProperties(o) {
  var seenobj = new Set();
  var seenprop = new Set();
  function _proto(obj) {
    return obj instanceof Object ?
           Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) :
           obj.constructor.prototype;
  }
  function _properties(obj) {
    var ret = [];
    if (obj === null || seenobj.has(obj)) { return ret; }
    seenobj.add(obj);
    if (obj instanceof Object) {
      var ps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);
      for (var i = 0; i < ps.length; ++i) {
        if (!seenprop.has(ps[i])) {
          ret.push(ps[i]);
          seenprop.add(ps[i]);
        }
      }
    }
    return ret.concat(_properties(_proto(obj)));
  }
  return _properties(o);
}
```

This function has four local variables: `_proto`, `_properties`, `seenobj`, `seenprop`.  The first one, `_proto` is a helper function to streamline computing an object's prototype.  The second one, `_properties`, is a recursive function, and it actually does all the work.  The third one, `seenobj`, is a  (ECMAScript 6) `Set` object used to keep track of the objects already encountered in the recursion (and therefore avoid infinite recursion).  The fourth one, `seenprop`, also a `Set` object, similarly keeps track of the names of properties already seen, and thus ensures that property names are not repeated in the returned value.  (NOTE: `Set` objects are available only in a few browsers.  An obvious improvement would be to replace these objects with a more portable alternative.)

If the argument `obj` of `_properties` is `null`, or if it is already present in `seenobj`, `_properties` returns an empty array.  (These are the conditions that terminates the recursion.)

Otherwise, if `obj` is an instance of `Object`, `_properties` gets the list of its properties with `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`.  `_properties` then returns as its result the array consisting of those properties of `obj` (if any) that are not already in the `seen` variable concatenated with the array returned by a recursive call with `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)` as argument.

Here's `getProperties` applied to some standard items (the interaction shown is  from the Firefox/Firebug console, though I've added line breaks in the output to avoid long lines):

```
>>> getProperties({})
[]
>>> getProperties(0)
["constructor", "toSource", "toString", "toLocalString", "toFixed", "toExponential",
"toPrecision"]
>>> getProperties("")
["length", "constructor", "quote", "toSource", "toString", "valueOf", "substring",
"toLowerCase", "toUpperCase", "charAt", "charCodeAt", "contains", "indexOf", "lastIndexOf",
"startsWith", "endsWith", "trim", "trimLeft", "trimRight", "toLocaleLowerCase",
"toLocaleUpperCase", "localeCompare", "match", "search", "replace", "split", "substr",
"concat", "slice", "bold", "italics", "fixed", "fontsize", "fontcolor", "link", "anchor",
"strike", "small", "big", "blink", "sup", "sub", "iterator"]
>>> getProperties([])
["length", "constructor", "toSource", "toString", "toLocaleString", "join", "reverse",
"sort", "push", "pop", "shift", "unshift", "splice", "concat", "slice", "indexOf",
"lastIndexOf", "forEach", "map", "reduce", "reduceRight", "filter", "some", "every",
"iterator"]
>>> getProperties(function () {})
["prototype", "length", "name", "arguments", "caller", "constructor", "toSource",
"toString", "apply", "call", "bind", "isGenerator"]
```

Thanks for reading this.  I look forward to your comments.

---

EDIT: The code shown above incorporates fixes to various problems that I noticed after posting the original version.  This original version is shown below, FWIW.

```
function getProperties(o) {
  var seen = {};
  function _properties(obj) {
    var ret = [];
    if (obj === null) {
      return ret;
    }
    try {
      var ps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);
    }
    catch (e if e instanceof TypeError &&
                e.message === "obj is not an object") {
      return _properties(obj.constructor.prototype);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < ps.length; ++i) {
      if (typeof seen[ps[i]] === "undefined") {
        ret.push(ps[i]);
        seen[ps[i]] = true;
      }
    }
    return ret.concat(_properties(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)));
  }
  return _properties(o);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you said, I have a little issue with the use of a try/catch statement. I tried to write it again using, imo, neater constructs:

```
function getProperties(o) {
    var results = []; 
    function properties(obj) {
        var props, i;
        if (obj == null) {
            return results;
        }   
        if (typeof obj !== 'object' && typeof obj !== 'function') {
            return properties(obj.constructor.prototype);
        }   
        props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj);
        i = props.length;
        while (i--) {
            if (!~results.indexOf(props[i])) {
                results.push(props[i]);
            }   
        }   
        return properties(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj));
    }   
    return properties(o);
}
```

There is one big difference between my code and your code though: you remove all the properties of `object` on the line `typeof seen[ps[i]] === "undefined"`. I don't know if it was intended behaviour or not; just pointing out!